# Unable to load imageView using nostra13 Universal Image loader android .

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

Hi all I am trying to display an image using UniversalImageLoader by nostra13. I have no idea how to get the failReason. This is my code to load an image uri. I am using de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView for this.

```
CircleImageView profilePhoto = findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
imageLoader.displayImage(user.getImage_path(),profilePhoto,new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"started");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    Log.i(TAG,imageUri);
                    failReason.getCause();
                    Log.i(TAG,failReason.getType().toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"YAY");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

                }
            });
```

The String image Uri is a content provider uri as I am trying to load this image from my phone's storage.

```
imageUri : content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38
```

As I know Universal Image Loader is able to load content provider Uri. I am not sure how to view the error also. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: remove spaces from url if exist

Comment: give us your image link (print image link in log)

Comment: The imageUri Above is the image link ? The image uri above is what is printed in the log

Comment: add ext in end like image%3A38.jpg

Comment: @Waleed Asim Hi it didn't work. I changed the line to  imageLoader.displayImage(user.getImage_path() + ".jpg" ,profilePhoto,new ImageLoadingListener() {..} and the log printed out the same path with a .jpg . content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38.jpg

Comment: @Waleed Asim hi I managed to solve it. Thanks for ur replies !

Answer (score 0):

All right so I figured it out after sieving through the logs I was getting a Security exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{500992e 4972:com.example.recouture/u0a83} (pid=4972, uid=10083) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

because what I did was I chose a image from gallery in another activity and uploaded that uri to firebase. So in another activity, I was going to read the uri from firebase and set it to a image in the current activity I am in. However , my current activity did not have the required permissions to do it even though the activity I uploaded the uri did. What I did to circumvent this issue was to upload the image using firebase storage and store the uri into the object I am uploading to firebase. Then in the activity that I want to retrieve the Uri, I can easily use ImageLoader to display the uri from firebase. Sorry for not posting all the code as I didn't think that I would come across such error. Hope this helps someone.